# Problem with references in printf (time difference program)

Tags: c++

I learn C++, pointers/references, some basic stuff. I made a little program that calculate difference between two times. My program works fine, but i have no idea why it returns a big value like 123123123:53442344 at the end when there are a & signs before variables. There`s a code of my program

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int userHour, userMinutes;

    printf_s("Enter first hour: ");
    scanf_s("%d:%d", &userHour, &userMinutes);

    int difference = userHour * 60 + userMinutes;

    printf_s("Enter second hour: ");
    scanf_s("%d:%d", &userHour, &userMinutes);

    difference = abs(difference - (userHour * 60 + userMinutes));
    userHour = difference / 60;
    userMinutes = difference % 60;

    printf("Difference is %02d:%02dh", &userHour, &userMinutes);
}
```

The problem is in the last line of code, i couldn't find an answer in a debugger or Google (inb4 i'm pretty new in programming, show me how to look for answers :( )

Comment: C or C++? They're different languages; please pick one.

Comment: I have removed the C tag since it is not valid C, though the things that make it "not C" are irrelevant to the code.  It is not at all clear why `<iostream>` is included.  Note that in C++ a "reference" is a specific thing distinct from a pointer - this code does not use references.

Comment: Using `printf` with `%02d` expects an `int`, not an address to an `int`.

Comment: Don't confuse `scanf` with `printf` for input you need somewhere to write the values, for output you just need the values - not their addresses.

Comment: If you are learning C++, you should be using `std::cout <<` and `std::cin >>` for output and input, not the C library functions like `printf`. You are also mixing different variants of the IO functions, which work different (e.g. `printf` vs `printf_s`). It is unclear why you are mixing these. You need a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to teach you the language. Throwing random stuff together does not work in C++.

Answer (score 1):

`&userHour` means *give me a pointer to the memory address of `userHour`*. Thus printf will print the value of that memory address. (Note, not the value stored in memory at that address, the numerical value of the memory address itself.)

You want `printf("Difference is %02d:%02dh", userHour, userMinutes);`.